# Consecutive calculations in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to implement this logic in Clojure (just an example):

```
a = 1 + 5
b = a + 3
c = a + 4
d = c + a
return f(a, b, c, d)
```

The best code I've managed to write so far looks like:

```
(let [a (+ 1 5) b (+ a 3) c (+ a 4) d (+ c a)] (f a b c d))
```

This looks rather cumbersome, mostly because in my real-life case these "add" operations are much more complicated and may take a few lines of code. I would rather prefer to write it like (Lisp style):

```
(set a (+ 1 5))
(set b (+ a 3))
(set c (+ a 4))
(set d (+ c a))
(f a b c d)
```

Is it possible in Clojure?

Comment: Wouldn't moving the pairs within `let` to separate lines make it look about as clear as the Lisp bit?

Comment: **About** as clear...

Comment: Frankly, I find Clojure's syntax better (retyping set over and over seems pointless). My opinion may be biased as I've only seen the simplified example you provided.

Comment: You could do `(def a (+ 1 5))` for variables at the root level, but in a method I'd definitely go with the `let`.

Answer (score 4):

No and that is by intent, as the `(set ...)` calls you're describing imply the use of *mutable state* in the way languages like Java and C# do. This is something Clojure actively avoids in order to manage state in a more sane way, something that really becomes important in concurrency. For more information I refer you to [the Clojure website](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming).

Furthermore, the `let` form is not cumbersome, it is a useful scoping tool: 
In your example `a`, `b`,`c` and `d` are all local to let. What this means is that once the instruction pointer steps out of the let, all of those bindings are forgotten.

In contrast, even if your `(set...)` example were to work, you would have polluted your namespace with all of these ephemeral names.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you almost found the best solution possible in Clojure:

```
(let [a (+ 1 5)
      b (+ a 3)
      c (+ a 4)
      d (+ c a)]
  (f a b c d))
```

You can't write Clojure code in imperative style, because it's a functional language. You can't freely use defs either, because all variables in Clojure are immutable. So, ones defined the can't be changed. So, if you want to temporary bind some variables, you should use `let`.

Answer (score 2):

The [set function](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/set) in Clojure creates a set data type from another collection container as opposed to mutating the values of the variables. However, you could do the following:

```
(def a (+ 1 5))
(def b (+ a 3))
(def c (+ a 4))
(def d (+ c a))
(f a b c d)
```

The let statement allows you to do the same thing but not "pollute" your top-level namespace with the `a`, `b` , `c`, and `d` values. However, if you want to be able to hang on to and reference `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, a `def` would do the trick.